# Connect DialogFlow agent to a different Firebase project

Tags: firebase, dialogflow-es

I have a DialogFlow agent set up on my Google account. When I set up fulfillment for the agent with Firebase, it automatically set up a new Firebase project for the agent. But I wish to connect the agent to an existing Firebase project.

I have admin access to both Dialogflow and Firebase but I am unable to change the service account on the Dialogflow agent. How do I go about changing the agent or a service account to connect the agent to an existing Firebase project instead of the one automatically connected?